# how to get the id for a post from within a post and return post meta for it

Tags: wp-query

I need to query for a post outside of another post: I am using a hook to import a page builder template and I need a query in relationship to the post it is hooked into. I not a huge fan of builders but they are popular.

I am using this code:

```
<?php 

$mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'post' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );


if ($loop->have_posts()) : while ($loop->have_posts())  : ($loop-      >the_post());

get_the_ID();  
//the_ID();
//the_title();

endwhile; 
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

and it works to a degree but returns all post not singular post data

That's it in a nutshell. query data from the post it's hooked into not from the post that the template was created with. It will return the id and title if I comment them back in but it does it for all posts on my dev box of type 'post'

Brad

Comment: Sorry, I am not quite following what you want to do.  Do you know what the post id is that you want?  If you so you can use get_post( $id ).

Comment: Hi brad, and welcome to WPSE. Honestly i didn't understand your question at all. Please try and make it more clear, possibly with answers. And prevent unnecessary explanation.

Comment: OK. I am using a query:

Comment: Let me get my thoughts together on this one......

Comment: The process of narrowing your problem down to a single, answerable question is often enough of an exercise that I answer my own question before answering it.  Focus on a very specific item and you'll have a much better chance of getting good, useful answers.

Comment: Updated the question....

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the post's ID from the $post object.
    $post->ID;